# Python. Exception has occurred: IndexError. List index out of range

Tags: python

> Exception has occurred: IndexError list index out of range   File
> "C:\Pyprojects\isPhoneNumber.py", line 11, in findSmallest
> smallest = lis[0]   File "C:\Pyprojects\isPhoneNumber.py", line 44, in 
> indexOfTheSmallest = findSmallest(lis)

```
import random

lis = []

for r in range(10):
    lis.append(random.randint(1, 60))


def findSmallest(lis):
    """ Finds the smallest number index in a list. """
    smallest = lis[0]
    smallest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(lis)):
        if lis[i] < smallest:
            smallest = lis[i]
            smallest_index = i
    return smallest_index


def findBiggest(lis):
    """ FInd the biggest number index in a list. """
    biggest = lis[0]
    biggest_index = 0
    for i in range(1, len(lis)):
        if lis[i] > biggest:
            biggest = lis[i]
            biggest_index = i
    return biggest_index


def selectionSort(lis):
    """ Selection sort algorithm implementation. """
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        smallest = findSmallest(lis)
        newArr.append(lis.pop(smallest))
    return newArr


sortedlist = selectionSort(lis)
print(sortedlist)


indexOfTheSmallest = findSmallest(lis)
indexOfTheBiggest = findBiggest(lis)

print("list: " + str(lis))
print("the biggest number index: " + str(indexOfTheBiggest))
print("the smallest number index: " + str(indexOfTheSmallest))
```

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selectionSort` mutates the argument it's given (`pop`ing off elements as it goes). When `sortedlist = selectionSort(lis)` completes, `lis` is empty, so `indexOfTheSmallest = findSmallest(lis)` is passed an empty `list`, and dies trying to index element `0` (there are no elements at all).

If you wish to make `selectionSort` non-mutating, copy the argument on receiving it, e.g.

```
def selectionSort(lis):
    """ Selection sort algorithm implementation. """
    lis = list(lis)  # Make copy to avoid mutating caller; explicit conversion to list means
                     # non-list iterables accepted too, like sorted built-in
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        smallest = findSmallest(lis)
        newArr.append(lis.pop(smallest))
    return newArr
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting function calls `pop(index)` so `lis` becomes empty after the line

```
sortedlist = selectionSort(lis)
```

Then you try to find the index of the smallest element in an empty list, which causes an exception when you try to get the first element by `smallest = lis[0]`.